# Invert regex with sequenction

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have this regular expression

```
/(\w)\1{3,}/
```

for found if string contains 3 or more same chars behind (like `johhhhn`).

Is there any easy possibilities how this regex invert to not match?

Comment: Yes, [look](https://regex101.com/r/oK0dG7/1).

Comment: The easiest way would be to do it in your program logic. Also this matches 4 or more same characters. If you insist, use a negative look ahead.

Comment: FWIW, I would probably do this in the language of choice.  IE change `if (regex.match...` to `if (!regex.match...`

Comment: yOur regex should match  4 or more similar chars not 3 or more.

Comment: What's the tool/language you're using?

Answer (score 1):

To exclude words with 4 or more consecutive characters of the same kind try negative [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
\b(?!\w*?(\w)\1{3})\w+
```

[image]

- `\b` the lookahead is triggered at each [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
- `(?!\w*?(\w)\1{3})` and looks ahead if there is not 4 consecutives

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nB0nN1/2)